# Where did the status icons go in GNOME 3.26.x and what can I do to bring them back?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

I updated to the newest, 3.26.1, version of GNOME several hours ago, and I don't see the list of background applications that used to be located in the bottom-left corner of the screen, on a hidden sliding panel. The icons belonging to Audacious, VLC, Dropbox, Redshift and other applications I run in the background don't see anywhere in the screen.

I opened the *Tweaks* app (or equivalently the `gnome-tweak-tool` command) looking for relevant configurations with no results. What happened to this feature, and is there a way to have one similar to it if it is gone?

*Source [Status Icons and GNOME](https://blogs.gnome.org/aday/2017/08/31/status-icons-and-gnome/), Form and Function Allan Day's blog*
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The legacy tray was [removed in 3.26](https://blogs.gnome.org/aday/2017/08/31/status-icons-and-gnome/) (it was a stop-gap measure, destined to be removed at some point, as explained in the [corresponding bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=785956)). This is also mentioned in the [release notes](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.26/).

To see your indicator icons, you can use an extension such as [TopIcons Plus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/).

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple ways how to bring tray icons back.

#### AppIndicator Support

[image]

The way I use and I would recommend to you is the appindicator-support Gnome extension. There are multiple implementations:

- **[KStatusNotifierItem/AppIndicator Support](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/)** - The default one and the best way for beginners. It may be already preinstalled on some Linux distributions.
- **[appindicatorsupport@rgcjonas.gmail.com.zip](https://github.com/bilelmoussaoui/Hardcode-Tray/files/5008706/appindicatorsupport%40rgcjonas.gmail.com.zip)** - **(Outdated for Gnome 40)** Patched version of the previous one. It is not distributed in the extensions store so you have to download, extract and place it manually into `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`. But it offers a lot of configuration options.

Each of these solutions also offers great integration into gnome-shell as it uses default dropdowns.

#### TopIcons

[image]

Another approach to bring tray icons back is TopIcons family of extensions. It all started with (**no longer functional today**) [TopIcons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/) extension.

- **[TopIconsFix](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1674/topiconsfix/)** - Fixed version of TopIcons. It doesn't provide configuration and icons are too large to look nice. I don't very recommend this one.
- **[TopIcons Plus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/)** - (The one on screenshot) This is a good extension. Provides configuration and icons look nice.
- **[TopIcons Redux](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1497/topicons-redux/)** - Rewritten fork of TopIcons Plus. It may not work in the newest version of Gnome-shell.

Note: Keep in mind you may not be able to get all your tray icons working with TopIcons extensions.

#### Additions

Some programs with non-working tray icons can be fixed by changing the environmental variable `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` before launching them. Try to change this variable to `Unity` or `KDE`. Test your program with the following commands:

- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity program`
- `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE program`

If one of the commands work, you can edit .desktop file of your program in `~/.local/share/applications/` or `/usr/share/applications/` to include this environmental variable in `Exec=` parameter.

`Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE program`

---

Some users may be looking into a way to customize their tray icons to look united and to match the system icon theme (as on my screenshots above). In that case, take a look at **[Hardcode-Tray](https://github.com/bilelmoussaoui/Hardcode-Tray/)** project.

Comment: In newer versions of TopIconPlus this change is already embedded

Comment: this solution does not yet work for dropbox

Comment: @KiranTelukunta Dropbox works fine in [KStatusNotifierItem/AppIndicator Support](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/) for me.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a GNOME shell extension called "[KStatusNotifierItem/AppIndicator Support](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/)". It has features like

> - Show indicator icons in the panel.
> - Reveal indicator menus upon click.
> - Double clicking an icon will activate the application window (if implemented by the indicator).
> - Middle mouse click an icon to send a 'SecondaryActivate' event to the application. Support needs to be implemented in the application.

(from [GitHub page](https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator))

**But** it fails to show some application icons, for example icons for electron based apps such as Skype.

Comment: TopIcons Plus (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/) display the icons KStatusNotifierItem/AppIndicator can't.